# Regex to parse percentage range from given string

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to form regex which should be able to extract percentage range from any String. For example- Adidas **30-60%** Off on footwear,

I am able to extract 60% from this string using - **`\\b\\d+(?:%|percent\\b)`** , But, this should work for both **56%** as well as **30-60%**.

Any help will be appriciaed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:\d+[—–-])?\d+(?:%|percent\b)
```

With fractions support it may look like

```
\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[—–-])?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:%|percent\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XlT0s0/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[—–-])?` - an optional sequence of one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits and then a dash
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
- `(?:%|percent\b)` - `%` or `percent` followed with a word boundary.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/zHA7yk):

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "both 56% as well as 30-60%.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:\\d+[—–-])?\\d+(?:%|percent\\b)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group()); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
56%
30-60%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "Adidas 30-60% Off";
        String pattern = "\\b[\\d|-]+(?:%|percent\\b)";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
```